# Adding subscribers to a list in Mail Chimp 3.0 in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am trying to implement Mail Chimp's new API with my ASP.NET C# website so when a user enters their email address into an input box it will be added to my mailchimp list automatically. I have tried various other methods however none of these have worked.

I have tried a Web Client which threw a 405 Cannot use that Method response and a HttpClient which threw an error on the starred GetStringAsync method call because its not a task.

My code so far is detailed below:

```
public bool BatchSubscribe(IEnumerable<MailChimpSubscriberModel> newSubscribers)
{   
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_defaultListId)) throw new ArgumentNullException(Res.Resource.MailChimpIntegrationNoListId);

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_apiKey)) throw new ArgumentNullException(Res.Resource.MailChimpIntegrationNoApiKey);

    foreach (MailChimpSubscriberModel subscriber in newSubscribers)
    {
        string url = "https://" + _dataPoint + ".api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/" + _defaultListId + "/";

        Subscriber member = new Subscriber();
        member.email = subscriber.Email;
        member.subscribed = "subscribed";

        string jsonString = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(member);

        //using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        //{
        //    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        //    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", _apiKey).ToString();
        //    string HtmlResult = client.(url, jsonString);

        //    return true;
        //}

        using (var http = new HttpClient())
        {
            http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                 new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", _apiKey);
            string content = await http.**GetStringAsync**(@"https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists");
            Console.WriteLine(content);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I'm a bit late to this question, but as it took me half a day to figure it out, here there is my answer, so it can help others. I'm using MailChimp 3.0:

```
private void subscribeAddress() 
{
  string apiKey = "APIKEY-usX"; //your API KEY created by you.
  string dataCenter = "usX";
  string listID = "listID"; //The ListID of the list you want to use.

  SubscribeClassCreatedByMe subscribeRequest = new SubscribeClassCreatedByMe 
  {
      email_address = "somebodys@email.com",
      status = "subscribed"
  };
  subscribeRequest.merge_fields = new MergeFieldClassCreatedByMe();
  subscribeRequest.merge_fields.FNAME = "YourName";
  subscribeRequest.merge_fields.LNAME = "YourSurname";

  using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
  {
      var uri = "https://" + dataCenter + ".api.mailchimp.com/";
      var endpoint = "3.0/lists/" + listID + "/members";

      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", apiKey);
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
      client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);

      //NOTE: To avoid the method being 'async' we access to '.Result'
      HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(endpoint, subscribeRequest).Result;//PostAsJsonAsync method serializes an object to 
                                                                                            //JSON and then sends the JSON payload in a POST request
    //StatusCode == 200
    // -> Status == "subscribed" -> Is on the list now
    // -> Status == "unsubscribed" -> this address used to be on the list, but is not anymore
    // -> Status == "pending" -> This address requested to be added with double-opt-in but hasn't confirmed yet
    // -> Status == "cleaned" -> This address bounced and has been removed from the list

    //StatusCode == 404
    if ((response.IsSuccessStatusCode))
    {
       //Your code here
    }
  }
}
```

Here there are the classes SubscribeClassCreatedByMe and MergeFieldClassCreatedByMe

```
namespace Subscriber
{
  public class SubscribeClassCreatedByMe 
  {
    public string email_address { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public MergeFieldClassCreatedByMe merge_fields { get; set; }
  }
}
namespace Subscriber
{
  public class MergeFieldClassCreatedByMe
  {
    public string FNAME { get; set; }
    public string LNAME { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Well, I hope this help!!

Comment: While using same parameters through Postman, I am getting Error `403 The API key provided is linked to a different datacenter`

Comment: I am getting error in response `StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request'`

Comment: In my case I received a Bad Request response due to using bogus credentials (e.g. email: example@example.com). When using more realistic credentials it worked.

Answer (score 0):

401 isn't "cannot use that method" it's "Unauthorized". You've got an authentication error. From the looks of things, you're not quite doing basic auth the right way. [Check out this example](https://gist.github.com/bryanbarnard/8102915#file-simplehttpclient-cs-L36) for the details you're missing.

PS: the response that comes back from APIv3 is usually pretty helpful, so you should always make sure to look at that whole response, not just the status code.

Comment: Hi @TooMuchPete thanks for your response. I am currently getting a 404 error code whenever I try and send the json data to mailchimp.

This is the message being sent:

{Method: GET, RequestUri: 'https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/myListKey/{"email":"testemail@test.com","subscribed":"subscribed"}', Version: 1.1, Content: <null>, Headers:
{
  Authorization: Basic myAPIkey
}}

Comment: That doesn't look like something you ought to be sending to MailChimp. If you're trying to make a GET request, you shouldn't be sending any body at all. What are you getting back in the body of MailChimp's response?

Answer (score 0):

It works if you change auth to these lines:

```
String username = "abc"; //anything
String password = apiKey; //your apikey
String encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password));

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", encoded);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code snippet is should work on .NET Core 2.1 using Mailchimp API V3.0:

```
    string url = @"https://" + mailchimpInstance + ".api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/" + ListId + "/members";

     var info = new Info() { email_address = "example@gmail.com", status = "subscribed" };
        var infoJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(info);

     using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {

            var uri = "https://" + mailchimpInstance + ".api.mailchimp.com/";
            var endpoint = "3.0/lists/" + ListId + "/members";

            try
            {

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",ApiKey);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);
                var content = new StringContent(infoJson.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                 HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(endpoint, content);

                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("Response from server -> " + responseString);

                return Ok();
```

Comment: What is content, what is Info(), where's your catch? How do you have your bool set up? Too much missing here to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Add into References `MailChimp.Net.dll`
than you can define an interface like

```
IMailChimpManager manager = new MailChimpManager(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailChimpApiKey"].ToString());
```

than you can add or update your client in your MailChimp list

```
                Member m = await manager.Members.AddOrUpdateAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailChimpListId"].ToString(), new Member { EmailAddress = _email, EmailType = "html", Status = Status.Pending});
            m = await manager.Members.AddOrUpdateAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailChimpListId"].ToString(), new Member { EmailAddress = _email, EmailType = "html", Status = Status.Subscribed });
```

It is very simple.. I think...